# How to configure Apache2 on ubuntu DigitalOcean to correctly redirect all except one path

Tags: ubuntu, redirect, mod-rewrite, apache2

I am trying to setup Apache2 on Ubunti OS running on DigitalOcean droplet to:

1. If the path has this pattern: `https://example.com/api`, proceed with the request. No redirect necessary.
2. For all other paths, redirect to `https://web.example.com`,
3. In both cases, request/post/headers/other parameters need to be preserved.

I currently have this but it is not working

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        SSLProxyEngine on
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example/public
        RewriteEngine  on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api$
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://web.example.com/$1  [R=301,L]
#SSL certificate stuff here
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api$
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://web.example.com/$1  [R=301,L]
> ```

You don't specifically say what or how this is not working. However, there are a couple of issues here.

1. A 301 (permanent) redirect does not preserve the *request method* from the initial request. The browser will make a GET request on the redirected request, so any POST data is lost in the case of a POST request. You need to use either a 307 (temporary) or 308 (permanent) response code instead in order to preserve the request method.

   But note that 301 (and 308) responses are cached persistently by the browser. So, you will need to clear your browser cache (and any intermediary caches) before testing.
2. Since these directives are directly in the `<VirtualHost>` container (as opposed to a `<Directory>` block or `.htaccess`) this will result in a double slash at the start of the URL-path, because the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (which you are capturing in its entirety) includes the full root-relative URL-path, starting with a slash.

> request/post/headers/other parameters need to be preserved.

Not sure exactly what you mean here, but it's not necessarily possible to preserve all "headers" through the redirect, since this is, after all, determined entirely by the browser.

All you can tell the browser is the new URL to redirect to (as part of the `Location` HTTP response header) and the HTTP status code, to indicate how the browser should handle the response.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule !^/api https://web.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=307,L]
```

There is no need for the additional `RewriteCond` directive, since this check (that the request does not already *start* with `/api` can be more easily (and efficiently) performed in the `RewriteRule` directive itself.

Any query string is preserved by default through the redirect.

Note that this is currently a *temporary* redirect. If this is intended to be permanent then change to a 308 only once you have confirmed that it works OK, to avoid potential caching issues.

As noted above, you will need to clear your browser cache before testing.